# Retrieve the host port, of a container launched from Docker SDK for Python

Tags: python, docker

When I launch a container using the [docker SDK for Python](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html), I can specify the host port as `None` so that the SDK will pick a random available port for me:

```py
import docker
client = docker.from_env()

container = client.containers.run(
  "bfirsh/reticulate-splines",
  ports={6379 : None} # SDK chooses a host port
  detach=True)
```

The problem is that I **want to know after the run command which host port did the SDK choose**. How do I do that?

Comment: This might help : https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/2681#issuecomment-744730577

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to reload the container then use `container.ports`

```
import docker

client = docker.from_env()

container = client.containers.run(
    "bfirsh/reticulate-splines", ports={6379: None}, detach=True
)

container.reload() # need to reload

print(container.ports)
```

Output

```
{'6379/tcp': [{'HostIp': '0.0.0.0', 'HostPort': '53828'}]}
```

This is only in version greater than 4.0.2 (which is at least 4 years old now)

[Commit that added this attribute](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/blame/a48a5a9647761406d66e8271f19fab7fa0c5f582/docker/models/containers.py#L66)

Comment: But why the need to reload?

Comment: if its already running it is not needed, since it is auto assigned you need to reload https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#docker.models.containers.Container.reload

Comment: I'll have to extract the host port from the dictionary first and check if it does what I want in my code. You can help me by completing the answer if you want or give me some time to properly verify

Comment: well, what is the issue with that? something like `ports = [int(i['HostPort']) for i in container.ports['6379/tcp']]` should give you all ports of `6379/tcp` @LorahAttkins

Comment: This doesn't work work. As written I'm getting back `AttributeError: 'Container' object has no attribute 'ports'`

Comment: I guess proof that the `port` attribute exists in later versions is enough to mark this as done

Comment: have added, that is a commit made 4 years back

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately a `Container` object does not have a `ports` attribute (prior to 3.7.2 as @python_user notes). By printing the `attrs` dictionary I was able to find out that the host port is contained inside the `NetworkSettings` attribute. In my case retrieving the host port looks like this:

```py
attrs['NetworkSettings']['Ports']['6379/tcp'][0]['HostPort']
# container port specified at launch ^^^
```

A more general solution would be to avoid the container port (6379) and search for the `'HostPort'` key instead.

Comment: python_user solution works for me too; did you make sure to run `container.reload()` ?

Comment: fwiw my docker library version is `'5.0.3'`

Comment: @python_user `reload` shouldn't affect the fields of `attrs` just the values. I do have a `PortBindings` attribute but no `ports` in the container object. And now that I checked the version, mine is `3.4.1` ...

Comment: @python_user There's a codebase of million of lines of code and I'm not the one managing libraries

Comment: @python_user The error I mentioned from the beginning was `no attribute named ports`. An empty dict `{}` wouldn't give such an error, no existent is different from empty in Python